# Xcode: Check if UIButton is hidden, using NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, uibutton, save, nsuserdefaults, hidden

How would I allow the app to save & load the current state of a button (i.e. if it is hidden, how would I save this, so that next time it will be hidden)? Also, I have it currently set so that when a button is pressed, all the other buttons become un-hidden. How can I set it so that certain ones don't become un-hidden if they have been set un-hidden in NSUserDefaults if you see what I mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with Apple's documentation on [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003764) to get any additional information you need.

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
 [defaults setObject:myBool boolForKey:@"hiddenButton"];
 [defaults synchronize];
```

Then you can just pull it in the same way and set your hidden value.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
myButton.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:@"hiddenButton"];
```

**EDIT:**

This would be one way to implement, but it really depends on what you want.

```
myViewController.h

BOOL myButtonState;


myViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad {

   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
   myButton.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:@"hiddenButton"];

}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed {

  myButtonState = TRUE;
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:myButtonState boolForKey:@"hiddenButton"]; 
  [defaults synchronize];

}
```

Comment: great thanks! How would I set the myBool value in the .h file?

Comment: I would probably just make it local to where you are pulling the state of the button. BOOL buttonState; Then just fill it from the user defaults. If you need it globally, just declare it same way.

Comment: Not getting that, don't understand what you mean? Would you be able to provide a bit of sample code? Thanks!

Comment: I get an NSException error when I try to run the code. Here it is; http://pastie.org/2492710. Why is this happening?

Comment: I updated my code, but it is untested. I believe it is because bool isn't a supported data type for -objectForKey, so try it with -boolForKey. You may need to tinker with it, but I believe that is why it is aborting on you.

Comment: Try and store your value as an int rather than bool. You can move 0 for true and 1 for false. Go back and store as objectForKey.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3218/discussion-between-bill-brasky-and-james-anderson)