# Save UIButton state and load with NSUserDefaults

Tags: xcode, uibutton, state, nsuserdefaults, viewdidload

I was wondering how to detect whether the button was hidden or not, and how much alpha was applied to it. Then, when viewDidLoad is called, these values can be applied to make the buttons the same state they were left in when the application closed.

How can I code this?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as your title suggests, you want to use `NSUserDefaults`, then you can set them like this:

```
-(void)saveButtonState:(UIButton*)button {
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:button.hidden forKey:@"isHidden"];
    [defaults setFloat:button.alpha forKey:@"alpha"];
}

-(void)restoreButtonState:(UIButton*)button {
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    button.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:@"isHidden"];
    button.alpha = [defaults floatForKey:@"alpha"];
}
```

If you want to do this for multiple buttons, then you can use `tag`s to differentiate between them in the defaults:

```
-(void)saveButtonState:(UIButton*)button {
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:button.hidden forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"isHidden%d",button.tag]];
    [defaults setFloat:button.alpha forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"alpha%d",button.tag]];
}

-(void)restoreButtonState:(UIButton*)button {
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    button.hidden = [defaults boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"isHidden%d",button.tag]];
    button.alpha = [defaults floatForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"alpha%d",button.tag]];
}
```

Comment: brilliant - thank you! When I tried just the alpha code, it hid all of the buttons? Why is this?

Comment: I did an NSLog to find out what the new alpha was after the code has been applied and it said NULL.

Comment: @James: What happens if you just log `button.alpha`?

Comment: @James: You can try casting from CGFloat to float, though I'm not sure why this would be necessary; e.g. use `(float)button.alpha`

Comment: @James: Then set the alpha first.

Comment: How would I do this, what do you mean?

Comment: where would I need to set this? It's already set in viewDidLoad, anyhow but when another button is pressed to reveal the buttons, the NSUserDefaults statement is called...

Comment: I added it above NSUserDefaults but made no difference... Buttons still aren't showing at all!

Comment: What is there to do to make the buttons show? I have made them show by doing the NSUserDefaults save statement but when I reload the app, they aren't showing again. Must be something to do with the save function...

Answer (score 1):

To check out the button state, check this post: [Xcode: Check if UIButton is hidden, using NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322442/xcode-check-if-uibutton-is-hidden-using-nsuserdefaults)

Regarding the Alpha, try to ask for the return value of: self.button.alpha;

you can update the state (value) of the button and the Alpha button in an SQLite database. In the viewDidLoad method, call back the values from the database and apply them immediately. On how to do this, check out some more info on the web and you'll get there because the internet is filled with tutorials on the topic. Well, that's what I would do, SQLite is really useful actually; but perhaps there are other ways as well.