# How to save the button state using NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I am new to iphone.I have small doubt that is I have a button with name Sync off when we click that button the below action executes :

```
- (IBAction)syncOffClickedInRegisterUserScreen:(id)sender {
    if ([syncOnorOff.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Sync off"]) {
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 
    else {
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Due to the above code, when I click the button the title alternates.

How can I save the state of the button with different titles using NSUserDefaults. If anybody knows this please help me....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save UIButton state and load with NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324689/save-uibutton-state-and-load-with-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: You should probably considering choosing some 'correct answers' to your other 14 questions before asking anymore. People won't be so willing to help otherwise...

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a key to save this button example :

```
 #define KEYSTATE @"key.syncState"
```

and in your function :

```
-  (IBAction)syncOffClickedInRegisterUserScreen:(id)sender {

    // Get User Defaults
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([syncOnorOff.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Sync off"]) {
        [prefs setBool:NO forKey:KEYSTATE];
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync on" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 
    else {
        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:KEYSTATE];
        [syncOnorOff setTitle:@"Sync off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    // save 
    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

and then you can get the bool (in `viewDidLoad:` for example)
to set the button like this :

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:KEYSTATE]) {
    // Set ON
}
else {
    // Set OFF
}
```

Comment: Just to add a note : boolForKey will return NO if the key doesn't exist, so the default value will be Sync Off.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button;

// get nsuserdefaults
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// save selected state
[defaults setBool:button.selected forKey:@"myButtonState"];
```

Then later, after the app launches again...

```
// restore the selected state
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
button.selected = [defaults boolForKey:@"myButtonState"];
```